# Coldfusion inline email image from a database?

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using ColdFusion 9. I can upload an image to a sql server and put it into a varbinary(MAX) field (column), and I can create a Thumb-Size image in the database. I can also put an image file into an email inline. Now I'd like to put the Thumb Size (from the database) into the email inline. This doesn't work:

```
<img src="cid:#FileInfoQuery.ClientFileName#" alt="" />

<cfmailparam
file="#FileInfoQuery.FileThumb#"
contentid="#FileInfoQuery.ClientFileName#"
disposition="inline"
/>
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What does this code represent?

Comment: The code above is in the cfmail tag to include the image inline in an email.

Comment: A very brief google search on "cfmailparam image inline binary" suggests looking at the `content` attribute.